# How to convert Integer from database into string in textbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is a little piece of code I wrote to autocomplete my textbox from the database as I type:

```
        {
            SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection();
            connString.ConnectionString = "Data Source=************************;Initial Catalog=STUPELG;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****************;Password=**********";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            connString.Open();
            SqlDataReader dataReader;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM dbo.Entity WHERE Name LIKE @name", connString);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", "%" + tbEntity.Text + "%"));
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                col.Add(dataReader.GetString(0));
            }

            tbEntity.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
            connString.Close();
        }
```

However, I want to display two fields (EntityID, Name) out of the database into the textbox, but

1. I do not know how to display more than one field.
2. EntityID is an integer and I am not sure how to convert it to string in my code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should dispose your connection, command and reader objects with `using`. You should also specify the type and size of text SQL parameters `command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = "%" + tbEntity.Text + "%"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a textbox is not used to display more than one data coming from the database. But also notice that autocomplete is a tool to help your end users to choose while typing.
If you want to add also the EntityID you need to add it after the name in the autocomplete source.

First you need to change the sql command to retrieve also the EntityID field and not just the Name field

```
string cmdText = "SELECT Name, EntityID FROM dbo.Entity WHERE Name LIKE @name";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connString);
```

Then inside the loop that read the values you add both the Name and the EntityID as part of the string added to the autocomplete collection

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    string data = $"{dataReader.GetString(0)} {dataReader.GetInt32(1)}"
    col.Add(data);
}
```